# Using Doc-O-Matic (Express) with Delphi

Tags: delphi, documentation-generation

I am looking for a tool to generate Delphi source code documentation, and I want to give a try to [Doc-O-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/editions.html) Express (which is free). Are there any guidelines for beginners how to use Doc-O-Matic Express to document Delphi source code (managing doc-o-matic projects, preferred docblock style, complete docblock syntax, etc) ?

Comment: Free for non-commercial use only.

Comment: Doc-O-Matic as a tool is really very good but in the end, the quality of your documentation is only as good as the effort you've put in in commenting your code.

Comment: You can give a try to DelphiCodeToDoc (opensource software written with Delphi). Creating a first project is a matter of seconds. After, if you need more 'professional' features, try Doc-o-matic (which is VERY powerfull). http://dephicodetodoc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Another FOSS tool to generate source code documentation is SynProject - it's handle a full documentation workflow, from specifications to release notes, including tests, architecture and design; and of course an integrated parser to generate architecture documentation from the Delphi source code. See http://blog.synopse.info/tag/SynProject

Comment: @A.Bouchez thx for the link, I'm discovering SynProject !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [page](http://www.devjet.net/announcements/delphi-documentation-guidelines/) you can found a doc which can be useful for you [`Delphi Documentation Guidelines`](http://www.devjet.net/downloads/Delphi-Documentation-Guidelines.pdf). I used this guidelines to document my source code in this [project](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-wmi-class-generator/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with Doc-o-matic settings right now. The express edition is command-line only.

1. **Choose a comment style**
2. Comment your code
3. Generate documentation (a default project is enough to start)
4. Verify you comment coverage

Doc-o-matic support JavaDoc and XMLDoc (or even kind-of native comments). The tool it-self will help only if your code is already comment, or if you want to comment directly inside its IDE.

> If you like XML Doc or JavaDoc,
>   Doc-O-Matic does support both equally
>   well and all three styles are
>   supported when writing source comments
>   through the integrated editor back to
>   the source.

Comment: Note that the express version only takes comments from the interface section.

Comment: @pritaes: Right! and here is the link to the feature matrix (Express is really a bare version). http://www.doc-o-matic.com/features.html?tab=matrix